# Does Any Hindu Texts Say Anything About The Evolution Of Consciousness?

Tags: belief

Are there any text regardless the evolution of consciousness, how to improve consciousnesses, and so-forth? I'm not sure if this is correct, but the "jiva" mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Hindu texts related to Yoga schools of thought discuss about the evolution of consciousness. The [Patanjali Yoga Sutra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Sutras_of_Patanjali) is such an important text that describes about consciousness, mental activities and also mentions the practices required to improve the consciousness.

Consciousness is generally the faculty that creates the awareness of "I" in the *jiva* (being) and by default the awareness of a *jiva* stays limited only to its body and its related objects. The purpose of evolution of consciousness is to expand it such that it merges with the universal consciousness and the *jiva* attains *kaivalya* (liberation).

Through practice of positive traits like friendliness, compassion, etc. one's consciousness gradually gets purer:

> *maitrīkaruṇāmuditopekṣaṇāṃ sukhaduḥkhapuṇyāpuṇyaviṣayāṇāṃ bhāvanātaścittaprasādanam* [PYS - 1.33]
>   - Consciousness gradually becomes peaceful through friendliness, compassion, delight, and equanimity toward all things irrespective of pleasant or painful, and good or bad.
>
> -Consciousness evolves or transforms along form, timespan, and condition as the elements and the senses. [PYS - 3.13]

The text is in aphorism form so understanding it directly may not be possible. Moreover, yoga being a physical activity to understand the practical implications of the text some expert's help can be required. Nevertheless, to answer the question evolution of consciousness has been dealt with very much detail in Hinduism in the yoga schools of thought. [Here is a link](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/ysp/index.htm) if you want to read that book online.